# How to use the stopwatch to measure the elapsed time between multiple points?

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I want to measure the current elapsed time in my code and the time elapsed between multiple code segments. An example:

When i want to get the elapsed time i am doing

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    _stopwatch.Start();

    ... do something ...

    _stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed total: {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", _stopwatch.Elapsed);
}
```

I can also output the elapsed time during code executing like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    _stopwatch.Start();

    ... do something ...
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", _stopwatch.Elapsed);

    ... do something ...
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", _stopwatch.Elapsed);

    ... do something ...
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", _stopwatch.Elapsed);

    ... do something ...
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", _stopwatch.Elapsed);


    // finally
    _stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed total: {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", _stopwatch.Elapsed);
}
```

But what i want to is something like this:

```
Code startet ... | elapsed time 00:02:01:sss | this single segment took 00:02:01:sss

Connected to database ... | elapsed time 00:02:04:sss | this single segment took 00:00:03:sss

Added 40.000 rows ... | elapsed time 00:05:23:sss | this single segment took 00:03:19:sss
```

So what i want is beside having the total elapsed time and the time stopped for the single sections in code the time for one single section beside the elapsed time.

How could i do this?

Comment: `_stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();` ought to be handy.  Don't worry about creating a lot of Stopwatch objects, they are tiny and have no extra overhead.

Comment: You will need to use two stopwatches one for the total time and the other for the single steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i solved it. For me it looks maybe some experts can check for "optimization"?

I am storing the last timespan in an vraiable and subsctracting the last on from the current one:

```
    private static TimeSpan _pastTimeSpan;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        _stopwatch.Start();

        _pastTimeSpan = _stopwatch.Elapsed;

        ... code ...

        MyElapsedTime(_stopwatch.Elapsed);

        ... code ...

        MyElapsedTime(_stopwatch.Elapsed);

        ... code ...

        MyElapsedTime(_stopwatch.Elapsed);

        _stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed total: {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", _stopwatch.Elapsed);
     }

    private static void MyElapsedTime(TimeSpan ts)
    {
        // Get the last TimeSpan
        TimeSpan pastTimeSpan = _pastTimeSpan;

        // Update last TimeSpan with current
        _pastTimeSpan = ts;

        // Get difference between two
        TimeSpan diffTs = ts.Subtract(pastTimeSpan);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Elapsed time {0}:{1} | Segment took {2}:{3}", Math.Floor(ts.TotalMinutes), ts.ToString("ss\\.ff"), Math.Floor(diffTs.TotalMinutes), diffTs.ToString("ss\\.ff")));
    }
```

And the output will be

```
Elapsed time 0:01.70 | Segment took 0:01.70
Elapsed time 0:01.78 | Segment took 0:00.07
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on STORMs answer I build a multi id / multi level Stopwatch. It can be used to measure parallel task with x level deep methods.

Usage Example:

```
public DataManager()
{
    StopWatchTimer.MeasureText(new [] { _stopWatchId }, $"CTOR loading ...");

    BuildDefaultExchanges(); _sw.MeasureText(new[] { _stopWatchId }, $"BuildDefaultExchanges");
    BuildExchanges();        _sw.MeasureText(new[] { _stopWatchId }, $"BuildExchanges");
    
    foreach (var exchange in ModuleGlobals.MicExchanges)
    {
        var defaultExchange = ExchangesView.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Mic == exchange.Mic);
    } StopWatchTimer.MeasureText(new[] { _stopWatchId }, $"foreach (var exchange in ModuleGlobals.MicExchanges)");

// More level 1 code

    StopWatchTimer.MeasureText(new[] { _stopWatchId }, $"CTOR loaded");
    StopWatchTimer.MeasureStop(_stopWatchId);
}

public void BuildExchanges()
{
    // level 2 code:
    Exchanges.Clear(); _sw.MeasureText(new[] { _stopWatchId, "BuildExchanges" }, $"ClearExchanges");
    BuildExchangesDefault(); StopWatchTimer.MeasureText(new[] { _stopWatchId, "BuildExchanges" }, $"ExchangesDefault");
    
    foreach (var exchange in Exchanges) // Level 3
    {
        ExchangesView.Add(new MicExchangeItemViewModel(exchange.Value, true)); _sw.MeasureText(new[] { _stopWatchId, "BuildExchanges", "Exchanges" }, exchange.Key);
    } StopWatchTimer.MeasureText(new[] { _stopWatchId, "BuildExchanges" }, $"Exchanges Build");

    BuildExchangesDefault(); StopWatchTimer.MeasureText(new[] { _stopWatchId, "BuildExchanges" }, $"ExchangesView");
}
```

Class:

```
public static class StopWatchTimer
{
    internal class Segment
    {
        public TimeSpan StartTimeSpan { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan LevelTimeSpan { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan TimeSpan { get; set; }
        internal readonly Dictionary<string, Segment> Segments = new();
    }

    private static readonly ICustomLogger _logger = ContainerLocator.Current.Resolve<ICustomLogger>();
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, (Stopwatch stopwatch, Segment segemnt)> _timer = new(); 

    public static void MeasureText(string[] ids, string text)
    {
        var mainId = ids[0];

        if(!_timer.ContainsKey(mainId))
        {
            // Time only needed in Level 0
            _timer.Add(mainId, (new Stopwatch(), new Segment()));
            _timer[mainId].stopwatch.Start();
        }
        
        _logger.Log(String.Join(" | ", GetSegmentText(ids, 0, _timer[mainId].segemnt, _timer[mainId].stopwatch, text)));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetSegmentText(string[] ids, int level, Segment segment, Stopwatch stopwatch, string text)
    {
        // For multilevel timer start segment at 0
        var ts = stopwatch.Elapsed - segment.StartTimeSpan;
        
        // Get the last TimeSpan
        TimeSpan pastTimeSpan = segment.TimeSpan;

        // Ignore SubLevel
        if (ids.Length == 1)
        {
            pastTimeSpan = segment.LevelTimeSpan;
            segment.LevelTimeSpan = ts;
        }

        // Update last TimeSpan with current
        segment.TimeSpan = ts;
        
        // Get difference between two
        TimeSpan diffTs = ts.Subtract(pastTimeSpan);

        // Time of the actual level
        yield return $"{ids[level]} Σ {Math.Floor(ts.TotalMinutes)}:{ts.ToString("ss\\.ffff")}";

        // Append potential sub levels
        if (ids.Length > level + 1)
        {
            if (!segment.Segments.ContainsKey(ids[level + 1]))
                segment.Segments.Add(ids[level + 1], new Segment() { StartTimeSpan = ts });
            
            foreach (var s in GetSegmentText(ids, level + 1, segment.Segments[ids[level + 1]], stopwatch, text))
                yield return s;
        }
        else
        {
            // time for lowest segment
            yield return $"Δ {Math.Floor(diffTs.TotalMinutes)}:{diffTs.ToString("ss\\.ffff")} - {text}";
        }
    }

    public static void MeasureStop(string id)
    {
        if (_timer.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            _timer[id].stopwatch.Stop();
            _timer.Remove(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
DataManager Σ 0:00.0006 | Δ 0:00.0006 - CTOR loading ...
DataManager Σ 0:00.0704 | Δ 0:00.0698 - BuildDefaultExchanges
DataManager Σ 0:00.0717 | BuildExchanges Σ 0:00.0000 | Δ 0:00.0000 - ClearExchanges
DataManager Σ 0:00.1249 | BuildExchanges Σ 0:00.0532 | Δ 0:00.0531 - ExchangesDefault
DataManager Σ 0:00.3456 | BuildExchanges Σ 0:00.2739 | Exchanges Σ 0:00.0736 | Δ 0:00.0008 - MIBG
.
.
.
DataManager Σ 0:00.8440 | BuildExchanges Σ 0:00.7723 | Exchanges Σ 0:00.5720 | Δ 0:00.0002 - KOME
DataManager Σ 0:00.8442 | BuildExchanges Σ 0:00.7725 | Exchanges Σ 0:00.5723 | Δ 0:00.0002 - IBER
DataManager Σ 0:00.8445 | BuildExchanges Σ 0:00.7727 | Exchanges Σ 0:00.5725 | Δ 0:00.0002 - ERBX
DataManager Σ 0:00.8447 | BuildExchanges Σ 0:00.7729 | Δ 0:00.0001 - Exchanges Build
DataManager Σ 0:00.8782 | BuildExchanges Σ 0:00.8064 | Δ 0:00.0335 - ExchangesView
DataManager Σ 0:00.8854 | Δ 0:00.8149 - BuildExchanges
DataManager Σ 0:00.8866 | Δ 0:00.0007 - CTOR loaded
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Restart()` method of Stopwatch after every elapsed time printed; it'll reset the elapsed time to 0 ...and keep one variable to keep summing the elapsed time as total elapsed time.

Hope this helps...